# JavaScript to save as current PDF with name derived from field but allow user to choose location

Tags: javascript, adobe

I am looking for help with JavaScript code to "save as" current PDF with name derived from field but allow the user to choose location where they want it saved. Can something like the below be used:

```
this.createDataObject({cName: this.getField("SCHEDULE_NUMBER").valueAsString+".pdf", cValue: __________});

this.exportDataObject({cName: this.getField("SCHEDULE_NUMBER").valueAsString+".pdf"});
```

I am not sure what "cValue" would be used to reference the current PDF or if this would be the best route.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

There is in Acrobat scripting a number of restrictions, so some script features need to be set-up as trusted by application configuration at a "folder" level. To allow scripts that modify at system level read https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsdevguide.pdf and https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/Trust-and-Privilege-in-Acrobat-Scripts.cfm

So too complex to cover all those requirements in a short answer. Basically since your attempting to seek ALL folders, you need to allow trusted documents to potentially overwrite across the systems folders.
see

> This is a common form feature requested in the Acrobat forums. Let me start right off by saying that it can only be done under very special circumstances. Saving a PDF to disk in the Acrobat/Reader environment is a protected operation. It's a security issue. Users would not be very happy if random PDFs downloaded from the internet could silently save themselves to disk. The user has to know what's going on. They have to either explicitly save the file using the File > Save… menu item, or implicitly allow the save through a trust mechanism.

From https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/How-to-Save-a-PDF-2.cfm#DiffName

However to answer your question with hints as to how to structure a document rename and save, here the script will read the field and then save as that name in current work folder, then start the option again.

Say we have file R100 and we wish to save as R101 then say Minor49R we simply enter that field, And I can run that script in another app but Acrobat will refuse for securities  sake unless I mess about with policy and privileges.
[image]

**So to prove that syntax I use another easier to manage Editor to set the field and transfer file control.**
[image]

so for what it is worth this is method I used

```
var schNum = this.getField("schNum").value;
var newName = schNum + ".pdf";
//app.alert(newName);
var filePath = this.path.replace(this.documentFileName,"");
var newPath = filePath + newName;
app.alert(newPath);
//HERE ACROBAT WILL NOT BE EASY to use
this.saveAs({cPath:newPath, bPromptToOverwrite:true});
```